# Regex for a blockhash in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, bitcoin

I'm trying to identify if a URL component includes a `bitcoin block hash`, which looks like `000000000d32098b5faf86d17cb6e1828ac98f3b104f019dd78bfc9fdc1ae7b0`

What's a regex I can use to identify that this is a block hash as opposed to a regular number or string?

Comment: It's a hexadecimal string with length n, `/^[0-9a-f]{n}$/`

Comment: Would `/^[0-9a-f]+$/i` not be fine?

Comment: No, because that will identify any hexadecimal string at least 1 character in length. GUID ids and memory addresses come to mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Blockhashes are always 64 characters in length.](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Block_hashing_algorithm)

`/^[0-9a-f]{64}$/i`

Answer (score -1):

If you want to match the strings which are having at least a digit(0-9) and at least a character(a-f), and overall length of the string is 10 characters. Then you can use this one:

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-fA-F])[a-fA-F\d]{10}$
```